# C: Multiple input from keyboard

Tags: c, input, keyboard

I'm trying to read multiple input from keyboard and store the input in variables.

**A snipet of my code:**

```
char answer = 'N';
int artnr;
char artname [27];
int stock;
double price;

while (answer != 'Y') {
printf("%s\n", "Enter article number:");
scanf("%d" , &artnr);
printf("%s\n", "Enter article name:");
scanf("%c" , &artname);
printf("%s\n", "Enter stock balance:");
scanf("%d" , &stock);
printf("%s\n", "Enter a price");
scanf("%f" , &price);
printf("%s\n", "Do you want to quit? (Y/N)");
scanf("%c" , &answer);
}
```

**Output:**
Enter article number:
1
Enter article name:
Enter stock balance:
25
Enter a price
4
Do you want to quit? (Y/N)
Enter article number:

Something seems to go wrong with my scanning. I guess it has to with the '/o' in the article name or when I press enter in order to confirm my input.

Comment: scanf leaves whitespace and new lines in the buffer. Flush stdin or try adding spaces like: `" %d"` to make it ignore these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`artname` is a char array and "Enter article name:" suggests you actually wanted to scan a string. 
So, this

```
scanf("%c" , &artname);
```

probably should be

```
scanf("%s", artname);
```

`scanf()` leaves the trailing newline when you scan with `%c` in the input buffer. You can ignore it by adding a whitespace in the format string:

```
scanf("%c" , &answer);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c" , &answer); // Notice the space in " %c"
```

A whitepsace in the format string tells `scanf()` to ignore any number of whitespaces in the input.

and change this

```
scanf("%f" , &price);
```

to

```
scanf("%lf" , &price);
```

in order to match the format string with the type.